# What is the appropriate answer to this clause?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, verbs, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

> Woman: Hi, how’s your new job going?
>
> Man: I’m trying to ____ with the fact that expecting a perfect job is unrealistic.
>
> A. bring it on
> B. get the news
> C. say to myself
> D. come to terms

I'm very confused between A and D. What do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: (D) definitely. (A) doesn't fit in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’m trying to **bring it on** with the fact that expecting a perfect job is unrealistic.

**bring it on** - used for saying that you are confident and excited about facing a challenge or contest [Source of meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bring-it-on)

I am very confident that you aren't 'that' happy or excited about the fact that you didn't get  the perfect job.

---

> I’m trying to **get the news** with the fact that expecting a perfect job is unrealistic.

There is no as such direct phrase or idiom which goes by these words. But it certainly isn't correct.

---

> I’m trying to **say to myself** with the fact that expecting a perfect job is unrealistic.

**say something to yourself** - to have something in your mind, especially something that you are trying to make yourself believe is true [Source of meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/say-something-to-yourself)

This phrase does the work in such situations, however the sentence construction would be different then, because the current sentence structure isn't right for this phrase to occur.

---

> I’m trying to **come to terms** with the fact that expecting a perfect job is unrealistic. [Source of meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-to-terms-with-something)

**come to terms** - to learn to accept and deal with an unpleasant situation or event, especially after being upset or angry about it for a long time

Very self explanatory sentence. You are trying to digest the fact that there is no as such 'perfect job' in the world.